# How to execute an arithmetic operation inside a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this little example:

```
var myoperation = "2+2";
var myoperation2="2*5/3";
var myoperation3="3+(4/2)"
```

is there anyway to execute this and get a result?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What all operations can the string have?

Comment: `eval`, which is also evil.

Comment: There's eval, or there's creating a script to parse the file manually.  Which you use depends on how much effort you're willing to spend, and whether this is user input or not.

Comment: `eval()` seems to work just fine. However, unless it is used very judiciously and cautiously, it would really break your code.

Comment: eval will parse and execute whatever is in the string, but it's slow and can be dangerous. The only other option would be to parse the string and do the calculations yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval` MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Some people say it is evil, but it was designed for this exact purpose;

```
console.log(eval(myoperation)); // 4
console.log(eval(myoperation2)); // 3.33
console.log(eval(myoperation3)); // 5
```

Comment: It can run any JavaScript code inputted. I'd say PHP's `eval()` is dangerous, but in JavaScript... whats the worst that could happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: Dont use eval, use

    (new Function(strCode))()   , check out what Jay Garcia and the team at ModusCreate put out in the link above : http://moduscreate.com/javascript-performance-tips-tricks/    Why? performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `eval()` function. For eg: `eval("2+2")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` for this.

[image]

Don't pass any data from a remote server to `eval` before validating it. Damage can be done with `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this besides `eval`:

```
function run(myoperation) {
    return new Function('return ' + myoperation + ';').call();
}

run('2+2'); // return 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the string to eval() function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```
var result = new Function("return " + "2+2")();
```